# does ListSamlProvidersRequestinput not exist?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk-go

I am working on finding a way to list Saml providers from aws with the go sdk.I am trying with the following code but getting nothing in my response. I think my issue is that I am getting the input wrong, however the go sdk docs don't actually specify what the input should be. even looking at the raw code on their github its essentially an empty struct any suggestions?

```
func idpFinder(account string,region string) []string {

var sess *session.Session

sess = session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
    Config:  aws.Config{Region: aws.String(region)},
    Profile: account,
}))

iam := iam.New(sess)
IdpOutPut := []string{}

input:= ListSamlProviderInput{}

req, resp := iam.ListSAMLProvidersRequest(input)

err := req.Send()
if err != nil { // resp is now filled

}
fmt.Println(resp)

return IdpOutPut
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the call should be something like this

```golang
,,,
iam := iam.New(sess)

input:= &iam.ListSAMLProvidersInput{}

resp, err := iam.ListSAMLProvidersRequest(input)

//  for _, sampProvider := range resp.SAMLProviderList {
//      arn := aws.StringValue(sampProvider.Arn)


err := req.Send()
if err != nil { // resp is now filled

}
fmt.Println(resp)

return IdpOutPut
}
```

As per the API [ListSAMLProviders](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListSAMLProviders.html) it just needs the auth params which are present in the client you are making, so it will retrieve from there. In your call, that's just an empty struct, so no auth params are present.

Comment: Super late response but the iam.ListSamlProvidersInput doesn't pull up at all when working with the sdk. I'm pretty much getting that the object doesn't exist when writing it  out the way you. have it written.